# Meteor.methods vs. standard JS function invocation

Tags: javascript, meteor

Can I place standard JS functions and invoke them as usual as well as invoke them from (Meteor) events? I am reading about Methods in Meteor and I am not sure if is okay to write some functions just inside my isClient conditional and invoke them as normal. I have something like this, which the second function 'normalize_scale_offset' is called by a Meteor event.

```
function normalize(val, max=1, min=0.1) {
        return (val - min) / (max - min);
    };

    function normalize_scale_offset(input, scale=1, offset=0) {
        var normalized = input.map((val) => normalize(val, Math.max(...input), Math.min(...input)));
        return normalized.map( (val) => val * scale + Math.sqrt(offset) ).map((val) => val * 1000);
    };
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean (if you can clarify your question that'd be great) Generally, you'd use methods if you want to invoke something to run on the server. If you're just running things on the client, just use a normal function.

Comment: Thanks, that was my question exactly. I tried the Methods way, but it complaint 'blaFunction' not found, as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, js functions are perfectly acceptable either on the client or on the server. Only when the client needs to invoke a function on the server is a *Method* required.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'd use methods if you want to invoke something to run on the server. If you're just running things on the client, just use a normal function.